# Is Christmas singular or plural

Tags: grammar

As an [ESL](https://www.esl.com/) user, I want to know which sentence is correct:

> Christmas **are** the best holidays.

or

> Christmas **is** the best holiday.

Comment: “Christmas are” is ***not*** a sentence, the complement/object is missing.

Comment: To the OP, with respect to the comment in the edit notes: "Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic". The site typically closes questions that can be answered with a google search. Also, https://ell.stackexchange.com is available for ELL questions.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks jimm101.

Answer (score 1):

No - not every word ending in 'S' is plural. It may be helpful to know that the origin of the word 'Christmas' comes from compounding the words "Christ" and "Mass" - a "mass" being an act of worship in the Catholic church. As "mass" is singular, it follows that "Christmas" is singular too.

The plural of Christmas would be **Christmases** (as in "*it's like all my Christmases have come at once!*")

"Christmas are" is not a complete sentence, so it is impossible to say it is right or wrong. Having established that Christmas is plural, you would **not** say "Christmas are an annual holiday" - that would be wrong. However, you could say "The family members coming to visit at Christmas are sleeping in the spare room". That is because "are" is operating on the plural *family*, not on the word "Christmas".